# Difficult with AutoPlay and AutoRun in Windows

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, autorun, autoplay

I feel pretty dumb at the moment, but for several days now, I have been completely confounded by the AutoPlay and AutoRun features of Windows.  In essence, I have developed some software that will be deployed via optical media (e.g., CD-ROM, DVD-ROM).  In a perfect world, our client wants the user to be able to simply pop in the CD and be off to the races.

We have explained to them that the actual AutoRun and AutoPlay features of Windows will be completely subject to the individual user's settings on his or her computer.  But even with that said, on my own machine, I have been unable to detect and use an "autorun.inf" file.

The software itself is installed using a .msi file that is launched from a VBScript.  Because the .vbs file is not directly an executable, I wrote a simple bootstrapper executable called setup.exe.  Here is my very simple "autorun.inf" file:

```
[autorun]
open=setup.exe
```

That's it.  No big deal.  If I manually double-click the setup.exe, everything proceeds as expected.  However, if I copy all of the necessary setup files to a disc (real or virtual drive) and insert the media, I do not have the option in AutoPlay to "Install or run program..."

I have tried tweaking my system AutoPlay settings to always install, and also to "Ask me every time."  I am not sure whether Windows is not recognizing my disc as a "Software and Games" disc, or if it is just ignoring my autorun.inf file.

In any event, no matter that I try, whenever I test this out, I ONLY get the "General options" section of AutoPlay with the choice of "Open folder to view files."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
[autorun]
open=command /c start setup.exe
```

Comment: Thanks, James, for the idea.  But unfortunately that doesn't seem to have helped.  Still only getting the "General options" in my AutoPlay dialog.

Comment: It really does seem like Windows doesn't even recognize that the disc should be qualified as "Software and Games" and present those options for me.  Like it never parses the autorun.inf at all.  I just wonder if I need to have something special about the contents of the disc to trigger that response?

Comment: Actually, we've been unable to get it working in either Windows XP or Windows 7.  Not sure if Vista has been tested.  It is a WPF application, so will only be installed on Windows machines.

Comment: Interesting. I'd almost certainly blame it on the machine (or maybe what you're using to burn a CD. I just tried with a memorex CD from staples on a Windows 7 Machine to run an exe and it worked.

Comment: I could try another machine.  So far on my machine, I have tried: (1) creating an ISO and mounting with Daemon Tools; (2) burning the ISO to a CD with ImgBurn; (3) burning the files directly to a disc with ImgBurn; and (4) burning the files to disc using Windows Explorer.  All to no avail.  Maybe I should try a commercial exe file, just to see if it's my binary?

Comment: that could be.  Please share the results.

Comment: Hi James.  Just realized I never responded.  Your approach did work.  It turns our that, to our best knowledge, it turned to be something pretty stupid.  I generally use Notepad++ as my text editor for tasks like this, and I think additional encoding was added to the file that prevented it from being parsed.  The exact same file saved in regular Windows Notepad was, if I remember, 4 bytes smaller.  Used that and suddenly worked.  It's always the little things...  :-)